Seeking product reference for an EM Noise reduction PCB Filter of DC motor
I have this DC motor (comming from an unknown bigger appliance), shown in the following photo.


There is an EMI/EMC noise reduction filter soldered on it.
The PCB of this filter can be seen in the following two photo.


I want to buy a new filter PCB like this one but I did not succeed to find a product equivalent to this PCB on my own research.
Can anyone guide me to get the reference of an identical product and a (reliable) online market place where I can find this product ?

Welcome -- unfortunately, as mentioned in the StackExchange tour, shopping questions are off-topic. However, you may be interested to know that PCBs are cheap and plentiful to make -- such a board might be product-specific, and it really doesn't matter as the cost of designing and creating the board is small. We are primarily concerned with electronic engineering topics here; if you like, you may edit to rephrase your question into one about EE topics, for example what inductor and capacitor values might be used to filter a motor of given ratings.

@Regman Please show the circuit, it may not be just the motor that is causing the problem. Also the cabling can be an issue. Are you failiing FCC?

@TimWilliams, Sorry for asking this question which goes against the rules. Though it is more a curiosity question than a true buying process, I understand that it is off topic now and why it is closed.
[at]VoltageSpike, my current purpose is just to know where this kind of filter can be found I am not actually debugging the motor+filter, but thanks for asking.
